# How do I change the shortcut for lock screen?

Tags: macos, shortcut, high-sierra

In macOS High Sierra, the new Lock Screen shortcut was added, but you can only use the shortcut  <kbd>^</kbd>   <kbd>⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Q</kbd> . I'd like to change it to something more Windows-esque, like  <kbd>⌘</kbd>   <kbd>⌥</kbd>   <kbd>L</kbd> . How can I go about this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can do this by following [this webpage instructions](https://maclovin.org/blog-native/2017/high-sierra-set-a-global-shortcut-to-lock-screen) :

1. Open System Preferences
2. Open "Keyboard" preference pane
3. Go to "Shortcuts" tab
4. Select "App Shortcuts"
5. Click "+"
6. Select "All Applications". In the "Menu Title" field type "Lock Screen" and press your shortcut
7. Quit System Preferences

Comment: 6. Select "All Applications"
6.a. In the "Menu Title" field type: Lock Screen

Answer (score 1):

Some shortcuts are not honored by macOS (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>Escape</kbd>, for example).

If you find that the default system shortcut tool doesn't work for you, you can add your desired keyboard shortcut using [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai).

This way you will be able to lock the screen with the default shortcut as well as your pre-defined shortcut.

Comment: BetterTouchTool let me use the exact shortcut that I wanted whereas the default MacOS shortcut tool did not. +1